# Sign convention confusion in work done problems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems, potential-energy, conventions

[Attempted solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwQ4K.jpg)

If I am using <WD=mgcostheta x chg in position>,do I ignore sign convention for g so I substitute g for +9.81 m/s even though I assign upwards as +ve because of costheta having taken into account that theta=180 deg? Is it true that each time I’m using WD=fcostheta, I do not need to assign sign convention on the force (mg) because the angle takes care of the sign?

Is the F in WD=F x Chg in position actually Fcostheta so the sign convention in F can be dropped bc the costheta takes into account the overall sign?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please avoid screenshots of equations, and also avoid external links that could break in the future. Type the relevent equations here.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714843/2451

Comment: Hi Kay. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Thanks Mods for the heads up!